# Linq query. List of 4 items becomes only 1 items in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am working with asp.net mvc and I am calling a rest service and receiving 4 receipts i a list (Se picture below).
The problem is that I want to convert the list of result that I have to a response result but still have the 4 items the the list.
When returning the response to my view instead of having **4** items in the list I only have **1** Store, **1** Receipt in the list.

What is wrong with my Linq query? I have addedd **.ToList()** almost everywhere.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

The asp.net

I have a model with a class as below

```
public class ReceiptsViewModel
{
    public List<RestAPI.Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public List<RestAPI.POSProvider> Providers { get; set; }
    public List<RestAPI.Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    public List<RestAPI.StoreChain> StoreChains { get; set; }
}

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Receipts()
    {
        Guid userId = Guid.Parse(CookieHelper.GetCookieValue("UserId"));

        var result = ReceiptService.GetReceiptsByUserId(userId);

        var response = (from r in result.Receipts
            select new Eflag.Receipt.Web.Mvc.Areas.Dashboard.Models.User.ReceiptsViewModel()
            {
                Receipts = new List<Models.RestAPI.Receipt>()
                {
                    new Models.RestAPI.Receipt()
                    {
                        ReceiptUniqueId = r.ReceiptUniqueId,
                        ReceiptId = r.ReceiptId,
                        CashierId = r.CashierId,
                        CashierName = r.CashierName,
                        ReceiptDateTime = r.ReceiptDateTime,
                        POSPlace = r.POSPlace,
                        Total = r.Total,
                        TotalTax = r.TotalTax,
                        TotalNet = r.TotalNet,
                        TotalDiscount = r.TotalDiscount,
                        Rounding = r.Rounding,
                        ItemAmount = r.ItemAmount,
                        Currency = r.Currency,
                        CurrencyCode = r.CurrencyCode,
                        MembershipCardUsed = r.MembershipCardUsed,
                        MembershipCardId = r.MembershipCardId,
                        Revoked = r.Revoked,
                        CardCompany = r.CardCompany,
                        FreeText = r.FreeText,
                        Items = (from i in r.Items
                                 select new Item()
                                 {
                                     ItemUniqueId = i.ItemUniqueId,
                                     ItemId = i.ItemId,
                                     Ean = i.Ean,
                                     Name = i.Name,
                                     CurrentPrice = i.CurrentPrice,
                                     RegularPrice = i.RegularPrice,
                                     Color = i.Color,
                                     ItemRowCount = i.ItemRowCount,
                                     ItemOrder = i.ItemOrder,
                                     TotalGrossAmount = i.TotalGrossAmount,
                                     TotalNetAmount = i.TotalNetAmount,
                                     Removed = i.Removed
                                 }).ToList()
                    }
                }.ToList(),
                Stores = new List<Store>()
                {
                    new Store()
                    {
                        StoreUniqueId = r.Store.StoreUniqueId,
                        StoreId = r.Store.StoreId,
                        Name = r.Store.Name,
                        CorporateId = r.Store.CorporateId,
                        Adress = r.Store.Adress,
                        PostalCode = r.Store.PostalCode,
                        Phone = r.Store.Phone,
                        Email = r.Store.Email,
                        Status = r.Store.Status
                    }
                }.ToList(),
                Providers = new List<POSProvider>()
                {
                   new POSProvider()
                   {
                        POSProviderUniqueId = r.POSProvider.POSProviderUniqueId,
                        Name = r.POSProvider.Name,
                        CorporateId = r.POSProvider.CorporateId,
                        Adress = r.POSProvider.Adress,
                        PostalCode = r.POSProvider.PostalCode,
                        Phone = r.POSProvider.Phone,
                        ContactPerson = r.POSProvider.ContactPerson,
                        Email = r.POSProvider.Email,
                        Status = r.POSProvider.Status
                   }
                }.ToList(),
                StoreChains = new List<StoreChain>()
                {
                    new StoreChain()
                    {
                        StoreChainUniqueId = r.StoreChain.StoreChainUniqueId,
                        Name = r.StoreChain.Name,
                        StoreChainId = r.StoreChain.StoreChainId,
                        Status = r.StoreChain.Status
                    }
                }.ToList()
            });

        return View(response);
    }
```

Comment: This single object is the last in the list you want to capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a list of `ReceiptsViewModel` instead of a single one with multiple receipts contained inside.

Change the code to something like this:

```
var response = new Eflag.Receipt.Web.Mvc.Areas.Dashboard.Models.User.ReceiptsViewModel
{
    Receipts = result.Receipts,
    Stores = result.Receipts.Stores,
    //rest of code snipped
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)
Why should be the r variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ConvertAll methon of List collection. Docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
var response = result.Receipts.ToList().ConvertAll(x=> new Eflag.Receipt.Web.Mvc.Areas.Dashboard.Models.User.ReceiptsViewModel() {
   //do your convertations here
});
```